# This add-in caused Outlook to start slowly

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, .net-3.5, outlook-addin

This message is shown on startup on Outlook 2013 for an Outlook AddIn developed using .Net 3.5. I have tried the suggestions in this post: [This addin caused outlook to start slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507350/this-addin-caused-outlook-to-start-slowly) 
But without any luck.
This is my initial method:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        _Explorers = this.Application.Explorers;
        _Inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        _Explorers.Application.NewMailEx += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailExEventHandler(Application_ItemReceive);
        _Explorers.Application.Reminders.ReminderFire += new Outlook.ReminderCollectionEvents_ReminderFireEventHandler(Application_ReminderFire);
        outlookNamespace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the windows registry is a time-consuming task which you can run on another thread. You should move such stuff to another thread to prevent your add-in from disabling. See [Performance criteria for keeping add-ins enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228679(v=office.15).aspx#ol15WhatsNew_AddinDisabling) which states the following:

> *Extending the add-in resiliency pillar of Outlook 2010, Outlook 2013 monitors add-in performance metrics such as add-in startup, shutdown, folder switch, item open, and invoke frequency. Outlook records the elapsed time in milliseconds for each performance monitoring metric.*
>
> *For example, the startup metric measures the time required by each connected add-in during Outlook startup. Outlook then computes the median startup time over 5 successive iterations. If the median startup time exceeds 1000 milliseconds (1 second), then Outlook disables the add-in and displays a notification to the user that an add-in has been disabled. The user has the option of always enabling the add-in, in which case Outlook will not disable the add-in even if the add-in exceeds the 1000 millisecond performance threshold.*

Comment: I get the same result without the registry task, I don't know where the time is being spent

Comment: Did you try to test a newly created empty add-in project? Do you get the same results?

Comment: When executing a newly created empty add-in project it doesn't add it to the list of slow addins, the error doesn't appear

Comment: It confirms my assumption that the issue depends on your code. Try to comment the code, uncommenting line-by-line you will find a weak place. Note, loading referenced libraries also takes some time.

Comment: Try to comment all the code, not only in the Startup event handler. Also take a look at the referenced assemblies.