# VSTO addin slow to start - Outlook

Tags: performance, vsto

I read the related post from Nathan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662790/2800651) but is still unable to improve the performance of the Add-in. The load function is pretty empty and running a step by steps using breakpoints gives me 178 ms and the addin report 1780 ms to load which is above the perf threshold. I am using VS2017 and .Net 4.5. Any idea on where I should look for thoss 1602ms?
I need to load the addin during the start of Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I did not find the answer but resolved the problem by placing all startup instructions in a thread:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
// My startup code
}).Start();
```

The downside is that you need to manage user actions while the add-in is not fully loaded.